# Git branching strategy for our Project

Tags: git, gitlab

I’m new to git and currently exploring the same, I would like to take some suggestions from the git experts here !

In our organization we are in the process of migrating to git from RTC. We have ~20 releases shared as a tarball in a ftp site and that has to be imported into git. 
In addition to that, a latest delta changes is also shared on top of the 20 release tarballs. Kindly let me know how to go forward with a best strategy.(like how to create branches or tags that suits the best to our case)
Also we have decided to go with gitlab latest version
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Workflow+strategies+in+Stash) doc for options on git branching strategies. It is related to Atlassian Stash, but can be applied to other tools.
There are several options, and you can try them all and see which works best for you.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to create an empty repo, unpack the first tarball there and commit. Then remove all working files, unpack the next tarball and commit. Et cetera until you've processed all tarballs.

Have a look at [git-weave](http://www.catb.org/esr/git-weave/). It can synthesize a repository from a sequence of tarballs.